# How to handle a constant parameter in a Poisson regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, poisson-regression, offset

I have a Poisson regression model with rate, $\lambda$, defined as $ln (\lambda) = \alpha + \beta + \gamma$. Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ change and $\gamma$ is 0.5 for each observation. $\gamma$ is intended as a boost to the rate, $\lambda$, for all observations. When I fit a Poisson regression model using the GLM library in Python, I expect to get positive coefficients for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and I do when I do NOT include $\gamma$ as a parameter.

My question is how should I include $\gamma$ in my Poisson regression model? Is it true that it must be included as a parameter that has a coefficient assigned to it? Or, is it the case that $\gamma$ is added after the model has been fit? Is it is the latter, then how can this be done?

Comment: Doesn't this library allow for an "offset"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want $\gamma$ to be exactly 0.5 you must add it as a parameter with assigned coefficient. Leaving it as an unspecified intercept will estimate the coefficient instead. Depending on the features and size of the data you're working with the model may find a value close to 0.5, but it will have extra variance compared to using a fixed coefficient. (Of course, if you aren't sure exactly what the constant coefficient should be, you can estimate it as an intercept.)

I'm not aware of any method to add it after the other coefficients have been estimated.

I'm not familiar with the Python library, but in R adding a fixed coefficient is done using the `offset()` feature. Here are 3 examples ran in R that show 1) An estimated intercept term. 2) When neither an intercept nor an offset is included the other estimates are biased. 3) Your desired model, with less variance than 1).

```r
    set.seed(1)
    N <- 1000
    constant <- rep(1,N)
    X1 <- rnorm(N,mean=1,sd=1)
    X2 <- rnorm(N,mean=1,sd=0.5)
    alpha <- 0.3
    beta <- 0.6
    rates <- alpha*X1 + beta*X2 + 0.5
    response <- rpois(N,lambda=exp(rates))
    
    mod1 <- glm(response ~ 1 + X1 + X2,family = poisson)
    summary(mod1)
    # Call:
    # glm(formula = response ~ 1 + X1 + X2, family = poisson)
    # 
    # Deviance Residuals: 
    #   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    # -3.2301  -0.7905  -0.1151   0.6556   2.9129  
    # 
    # Coefficients:
    #   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    # (Intercept)  0.55385    0.03990   13.88   <2e-16 ***
    #   X1           0.28965    0.01427   20.30   <2e-16 ***
    #   X2           0.57369    0.02843   20.18   <2e-16 ***
    #   ---
    #   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    # 
    # (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
    # 
    # Null deviance: 1913.4  on 999  degrees of freedom
    # Residual deviance: 1080.1  on 997  degrees of freedom
    # AIC: 4197.7
    # 
    # Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
    
    mod2 <- glm(response ~ 0 + X1 + X2,family = poisson)
    summary(mod2)
    # Call:
    #   glm(formula = response ~ 0 + X1 + X2, family = poisson)
    # 
    # Deviance Residuals: 
    #   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    # -3.0941  -0.5792   0.0852   0.9742   3.1652  
    # 
    # Coefficients:
    #   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    #   X1  0.37185    0.01329   27.97   <2e-16 ***
    #   X2  0.88172    0.01737   50.77   <2e-16 ***
    #   ---
    #   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    # 
    # (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
    # 
    # Null deviance: 8399.1  on 1000  degrees of freedom
    # Residual deviance: 1262.2  on  998  degrees of freedom
    # AIC: 4377.8
    # 
    # Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
    
    mod3 <- glm(response ~ 0 + X1 + X2 + offset(0.5*constant),family=poisson)
    summary(mod3)
    # Call:
    #   glm(formula = response ~ 0 + X1 + X2 + offset(0.5 * constant), 
    #       family = poisson)
    # 
    # Deviance Residuals: 
    #   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    # -3.2187  -0.7621  -0.1071   0.6792   2.9131  
    # 
    # Coefficients:
    #   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    #   X1  0.29796    0.01290   23.09   <2e-16 ***
    #   X2  0.60435    0.01706   35.43   <2e-16 ***
    #   ---
    #   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    # 
    # (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
    # 
    # Null deviance: 5213.5  on 1000  degrees of freedom
    # Residual deviance: 1081.9  on  998  degrees of freedom
    # AIC: 4197.5
    # 
    # Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. There is in fact an offset kwarg in the GM library in python.